# Shopify - access product image metafields with Liquid

Tags: image, shopify, liquid

Is it possible to access a product image's metafield with Liquid? I can successfully add new image metafields with the API, but when I attempt to display them using the instructions on the Shopify API Documentation website, it doesn't work. Here is the format they say to use: {{ resource.metafields.namespace.key }}. Is this possible to display custom image metafields with Liquid in Shopify? And if it isn't possible, why provide the ability to add metafields without the ability to output them?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the code your using to assign a metafield resource to an image here? That would be a goos start in trying to generate some useful help.

Comment: The metafield is already assigned to the image. owner_resource is product_image and owner_id is the image's id. The namespace and key are both set, as well. I can verify this using the API, as it displays the metafield as being successfully created and attached to the image. The problem isn't with the API, it is with displaying this metafield through liquid. Liquid doesn't seem to support the output of metafields attached to images using this format {{ resource.metafields.namespace.key }}

Comment: Very likely the core does not support your use case. They hacked in alt-tags as a metafield, but nothing else. Guess you'll have to make a  feature request for new core capability.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this yet? Trying to access customer/product specific metafields and accessing them via product.id but no go as of yet.

Comment: This was figured out 8 years ago. Either store a string representing the URL of an image, or store you image as a string and just render it that way... doing all the hard work you deserve to make your life interesting.